# Single regular expression with 2 matches

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Given the path

```
C:\Users\Bob\Downloads\Product12\Prices\USD
```

and only knowing it contains a subdirectory called `Downloads`

I have this regex to locate the Downloads part

```
(?<=Downloads\\)[^\\""]*
```

Ideally, I want to also match everything after Downloads as a separate group, but using a single regex for both Downloads and the following path portion.

Answer (score 0):

this will match everything before 'downloads' in one subgroup, and everything after in another subgroup:

```
/^(.*?Downloads\\)(.*)$/
```

Comment: That seems to match as: group 1 - everything up to and including Downloads\, group 2 - everything after Downloads\, but I just realised my question is wrong. Should I edit or create another issue?

Answer (score 0):

So given the sample input, you want to get `Product12\Prices\USD`, right?

```
result = Regex.Match(s, @"\\Downloads\\(.*)$").Groups[1].Value;
```

But that `[\\""]*` in your regex seems to indicate that your path is enclosed in quotes, and you don't want the match to the closing quote or anything after it.

```
result = Regex.Match(s, @"\\Downloads\\([^""]*)""").Groups[1].Value;
```

Some points of particular interest are:

- when you create regexes in C#, always use C#'s verbatim string notation if at all possible (i.e., `@"regex"`).  It saves you having to litter your code with a bunch of backslashes.  For example, if your regex were in a standard C-style string literal you would have to use *four* backslashes in the regex to match one backslash input.
- When you include regexes in your posts here at SO, show them as they appear in your code.  Then we won't have to guess what the backslashes mean.  For example, is the `\\` in `[^\\""]*` supposed to match a literal backslash, or are you just escaping it for the regex?
- Speaking of quotes, `"` has no special meaning in regexes, so you don't have to escape it for that.  I changed that sequence to `[^""]*` because that's how you escape quotes in a verbatim string.  In C-style string literal it would be `[\\"]*`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need RegEx to parse paths

```
var paths = new Uri(@"C:\Users\Bob\Downloads\Product12\Prices\USD").Segments;
```

would return all segments and you can skip till `Downloads`. For example

```
var paths = new Uri(@"C:\Users\Bob\Downloads\Product12\Prices\USD")
                .Segments
                .SkipWhile(s => s != "Downloads/")
                .Skip(1)
                .ToList();
```